# select2 twitter bootstrap css minor issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I am new into web devlopment. I am trying to use select2-bootstrap. It working fine. Just need a css help.

Initial display of widget :[image]

There is an indent between the bars(between `Search for a movie` and `No matches found`)

After clicking on the widget it looks fine as shown here and thereafter the dent disappears even on subsequent use.[image]

Can someone suggest how to remove the dent between two bars in the first pic above.

NOTE : 
CSS Added : select2.css, select2-bootstrap.css and bootstrap.css

JS Added : bootstrap.js, jquery-1.9.1.js, select2.js

Also please suggest how to avoid the `No matches found` display immediately after page loads.

Here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Twitter Bootstrap</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
    href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
    href="css/select2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
    href="css/select2-bootstrap.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/select2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var contextPath = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>";

    $(document)
            .ready(
                    function() {

                        MultiAjaxAutoComplete('#e6',contextPath + "/getData");

                        $('#save').click(function() {
                            alert($('#e6').val());
                        });

                    });
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
    function MultiAjaxAutoComplete(element, url) {
        $(element).select2({
            placeholder : "Search for a movie",
            //minimumInputLength : 1,
            multiple : true,
            ajax : {
                url : url,
                dataType : 'json',
                data : function(term, page) {

                    return {
                        q : term,
                        page_limit : 10,
                    };
                },
                results : function(data, page) {
                    console.log("page = " + page);
                    return {
                        results : data.results
                    };
                }
            },
            formatResult : formatResult,
            formatSelection : formatSelection,
            initSelection : function(element, callback) {
                var data = [];
                $(element.val().split(",")).each(function(i) {
                    var item = this.split(':');
                    data.push({
                        id : item[0],
                        country : item[1]
                    });
                });
                callback(data);
            }
        });
    };

    function formatResult(movie) {
        return '<div>' + movie.country + '</div>';
    };

    function formatSelection(data) {
        return data.country;
    };
</script>

</head>
<body style="background-color: #F9F9F6">
<h1>Serach Movies</h1>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span9">
                <input type='hidden' id="e6" class="span8" />
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <button id="save">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have quite the eye for detail, I use the select2 plugin in a web app of mine, it is a nice plugin. I do not readily have a suggestion for how to fix this issue other than to suggest that you do not worry about it. I make web apps with heavy traffic and no one has ever noticed this little "flaw" within my company or outside of it.

Comment: apart from what @Brian said, my only guess would be a negative margin (or top) on the results list.

Comment: @Thomas, can you please elaborate what you said above. How can I change the results list css. The issue shows only when the page loads and "No matches found is displayed" . After that it simply disappears when clicked once on the widget. Brian : thanks, but my manager needs it all clean :(

Comment: @PravatPanda I'm sorry, I thought this was an issue when the No Results message was displayed, not that it was being displayed incorrectly at page load.  I believe that is your root issue and fixing it will fix both.  Unfortunately, I don't know the solution to that